# Непонятные символы, а должны быть буквы русского алфавита

Tags: java

```
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileInputStream reader = null;
        try{
            reader = new FileInputStream("d:\\123.txt");
            while(true){
                int read_int = reader.read();
                if(read_int == -1) break;
                char ch = (char) read_int;
                System.out.println(ch);
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e1) {
            System.out.println("File not Found");
        } catch(EOFException e2){
        System.out.println("File ended.");
        } catch(IOException e3){
        e3.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally{
            try{
                reader.close();
            } catch (NullPointerException e1){
                System.out.println("NullPointerException caught.");
            } catch (IOException e2){
                System.out.println("IOException caught.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В файле 123.txt текст на русском. В консоль выводятся непонятные символы.

Comment: а как посмотреть?)

Comment: пробовал сохранять как с кодировкой Unicode, так и utf-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Консоль операционной системы Windows имеет кодировку cp866, а системная кодировка cp1251. Виртуальная машина по умолчанию считывает файлы в системной кодировке. Соответственно, если действительная кодировка данных - utf-8, считываются они в cp1251, а выводятся в cp866, получаете кракозябры. Либо исходные данные в файле должны быть в системной кодировке, либо вам придётся их перекодировать. Проще всего это сделать указав кодировку при открытии файла:

```
try (InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(
       new FileInputStream("d:\\123.txt"), "UTF8"))) {
    int c;
    while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print((char) c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Справа внизу экрана есть кодировка так вот она должна быть UTF-8**

[image: Смотреть вправо вниз]

*** *Если конечно вы пользуетесь Intellij Idea* ***

Comment: Такая и стоит, ide ту же использую.

Comment: Ну тогда не знаю.

Comment: Не сталкивался.